# How to resolve the "Cannot resolve constructor 'XSSFColor(Color)'"?

Tags: java, apache-poi

After upgrading apache.poi.version to 5.2.2, I get 'Cannot resolve constructor XSSFColor(Color)' error. Getting the error in below line of code.

```
protected final XSSFColor tdBlueColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 153));
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, like reading the documentation, looking at the available consrtuctors?

Comment: You possibly need to pass more than just a `new java.awt.Color(…)`, find more information in [the relevant docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/latest/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html) ;-)

Comment: That constructor was [Deprecated & Removed](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#XSSFColor-java.awt.Color-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In POI 5.2.2, one of the most common ways to create an XSSFColor is:

```
IndexedColorMap colorMap = workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors();
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new byte[]{51, 51, (byte)153}, colorMap);
```

Or use Hex, like:

```
final String rgbS = "333399";
final byte[] rgbB = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(rgbS);
IndexedColorMap colorMap = workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors();
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgbB, colorMap);
```

I used https://htmlcolorcodes.com/rgb-to-hex/?r=51&g=51&b=153 to convert the java.awt.Color values to Hex format (and got 333399)

Comment: The code `new byte[]{51, 51, 153}` will not compile as 153 is greater than the positive max value of `byte`, which is 127. So implicit conversion from `int` to `byte` will not work in this case. It would must be `new byte[]{51, 51, (byte)153}`.

Comment: How to get IndexedColorMap object from SXSSFWorkbook?

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook has getXSSFWorkbook() so you should be able to call getStylesSource().getIndexedColors() on the XSSFWorkbook associated with the SXSSFWorkbook

Comment: I tried this : XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook =  sxssfWorkbook.getXSSFWorkbook();
        IndexedColorMap colorMap = ((XSSFWorkbook) xssfWorkbook).getStylesSource().getIndexedColors(); it says ClassCastException

Comment: IndexedColorMap colorMap = sxssfWorkbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors(); this says Cannot resolve method 'getStylesSource' in 'SXSSFWorkbook'

Comment: this unit test seems to work - https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/8d9d916ecdf5e703def0b80eb4b1db30fd1e5e58